# Analysis results? What are those pink lines in Visual Studio text editor?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, profiling, resharper

I noticed pink lines in my text editor (better late than never)
After a few days. I managed to understand that is result of some kind of analysis, by keeping my cursor over it, so the tooltip had a chance to pop up (I am slow learner as you figured out this point)

**Question**

How and when this data collected, was it the last debug session? **How can I navigate to the 7 specific issues related to this line?** Is this something to do with the Dynamic Program Analysis at bottom right of the IDE window?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is part of the "Dynamic Program Analysis", which is a recent ReSharper feature. You can configure this in your ReSharper settings.

For navigation to issues they use their Stack Trace Explorer window.